# Onclick function don't run first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This function scroll from navigation to  #id using animation and colorizing it bg-color color for few seconds.

This is the function I use to scroll down from navigation to content using on the page by using it id `<h1 id="#someid">` and `href="#someid"` attributes in an anchor tags. The function works fine, however, it do not work on the first time click after loading the page. Any idea how to fix it and what causes it ?

```
//EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT

function link(){
          $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
              var target = $(this.hash);
              if (target.length == 0) target = $('a[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]');
              if (target.length == 0) target = $('html');
              $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 100); 
              target[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
              setTimeout(function(){
                  target[0].style.backgroundColor = 'dodgerBlue';
             }, 8000);
              return false;
     });
}
```

This is my HTML, I simply overwrite the anchor onclick property by linking it to my function's `link();` which you can see above this text.

```
//HTML 
<li class="sub-menu-element"><a href="#DERMATOLOG" onclick="javascript:link()">DERMATOLOG</a></li>
```

Any ideas? 
Many thanks for your help guys in advance.

Comment: A small note: You call `if (target.length == 0)` twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling a `link()` function from inline javascript  and again calling  the click event inside the `link()` function. which make no sense and  is not required at all...

try this

```
$(function(){ //call the codes after this when document is ready...
  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {  //call the click event
          var target = $(this.hash);
          if (target.length == 0) target = $('a[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]');
          if (target.length == 0) target = $('html');
          $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 100); 
          target[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
          setTimeout(function(){
              target[0].style.backgroundColor = 'dodgerBlue';

         }, 8000);
          return false; 
  });
});
```

and with this.. you don't need onclick inline too

```
<li class="sub-menu-element"><a href="#DERMATOLOG">DERMATOLOG</a></li>
```

Comment: I can see your point however in this set you have provided animation simple don't work. Like it do not trigger this function at all. 
Thanks for try anyway :*

Comment: since we have removed the direct link from an anchor tag.. can we still use "this." ?

Comment: yes you can... this should work....alert inside click event and in settimeout function to see if this function is called... see if you get any error.... you can remove return false from settimeout and and it to next line.. check my upadte.. and let me know

Comment: I am so sorry :) your code was right :) I had javascript file linked above the jquery reference. 

Your code works man. THANKS ! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `link` function only *sets up* the scroll thing. So prime on the second click the handler will be actually executed.

Throw away that inline handler with its wrong `javascript:` syntax, and put a

```
$(document).ready(link);
```

in your external js which will execute the setup function when the DOM is loaded. Also, I think you should move the `return false;` line one down from the timeout to the handler.

Comment: I have done as you asked my friend unfortunately it did not work.
Thanks Man

Comment: @Wiktor: Really? Why not, what error do you get now? It's basically the same thing as Igor and Bipen have provided.

Comment: It works ;*  I had javascript file linked above the jquery reference.
Your code is working thx man

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e){
      $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          if (target.length == 0) target = $('a[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]');
          if (target.length == 0) target = $('html');
          $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 100); 
          target[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
          setTimeout(function(){
              target[0].style.backgroundColor = 'dodgerBlue';
              return false;
         }, 8000);

      });
});
```

Comment: It did not work my friend is like since I have removed a onClick call from an anchor tag this can not find the links. Maybe is the "this." what stops it from working. Sins this is not call directly from the link any more.

Comment: @WiktorLiszkiewicz: Could you please tell us what excactly is not working? What error do you get? Please apply the changes you have made to your question as well.

Comment: it simple show no error but also it wont trigger the function when you click on a link. It skip the animation and it skips the h1 colourizing

Comment: Did you tried to add event information on this line?
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
Try to put this
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //call the codes after this when document is ready...
$('a[id="demo"]').click(function() {  //call the click event
      var target = $(this.hash);
      if (target.length == 0) target = $('a[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]');
      if (target.length == 0) target = $('html');
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 100); 
      target[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      setTimeout(function(){
          target[0].style.backgroundColor = 'dodgerBlue';

     }, 8000);
      return false;
```

});
});

```
<li class="sub-menu-element"><a href="#" id='demo'>DERMATOLOG</a></li>
```

Comment: Works fine! I just had to swap my reference order. first should be reference to jQuery and then reference to the .js file with this code. 
 
Thanky you guys for help all answers where good.